# select box value not setting on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Problem:**

A value of select box is **not setting** in modal,

But when **reloading a page** and open a modal it sets select box value.

**Expected:**

In both cases, select box values are loading correctly but the value is not set.

**jQuery:**

```
function showModal() {
    var selectbox_options = '<option value=""></option><option value="0"></option><option value="1"></option>';
    //Above selectbox options are dynamically created using jquery each.

    var selected_value = "0";
    $('#modal').modal({
      show: true,
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    });

    //I tried both by placing these below two lines above and inside show.bs.modal callbacks

    $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
      $('#modal').find(".dropdown-box").find('option').not(':first').remove();
      $('#modal').find('.dropdown-box').append(selectbox_options).val(selected_value).trigger('change');
    });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" onclick="showModal();"></button>
```

Comment: Your variables should not have a dash like `var selected-value = "0";` This will not work obviously

Comment: I corrected now. It was just a typo

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

You assigned the value as `selected_value` but used as `selectbox_value`

Also, I have given the option values too, in order to recognize the change in select box

```js
function showModal() {
  var selectbox_options = '<option value=""></option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option>';
  //Above selectbox options are dynamically created using jquery each.

  var selected_value = "0";
  $('#modal').modal({
    show: true,
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  });

  //I tried both by placing these below two lines above and inside show.bs.modal callbacks

  $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('#modal').find(".dropdown-box").find('option').not(':first').remove();
    $('#modal').find('.dropdown-box').append(selectbox_options).val(selected_value).trigger('change');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<button type="button" onclick="showModal();">open</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select class="dropdown-box"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: select box value is assigned to select box before appending options. select box become blank on modal open.

Comment: I construct select options using jquery each inside showModal function. something like this.  `$("div").each(function(index, value) {
    options += '<option value="' + $(value).attr("id") + '">' + $(value).find(".child-div").text() + '</option>';
});`

Comment: I think loop takes more time to execute. so next statement executes leaves select box with unselected value.

Comment: I fixed a bug. my selected_value variable had an extra double quote i.e., my selected_value variable had ""0"" instead of "0".